# 80s (70s?) Christmas scifi programme. Alien befriends young boy and dresses as Santa

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, santa-claus

I recall an alien befriends a young boy and at Christmas the boy is given a present from the alien dressed as Santa. The gift is a small toy version of its spaceship.

Comment: This question is very terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: -100 for reminding me of this movie. But +101 for actually having seen it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot believe I know this, but it is the French Canadian film [le martien de Noël](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/le_martien_de_noel_the_christmas_martian) from 1971. Two kids meet a Martian out in the snow, teach him a bit about the Earth (or at least, Quebec), and at the end, he dresses up like Santa and gives them a model of his ship. I watched it several years in a row in elementary school

Here’s a [quick video summary](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PHACZdlYPTU).

Comment: There are a few very good sci fi movies every kid should see. This... is basically the opposite thing.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, you have nailed this one, yes i watched a hell of a lot of things when i was a kid i probably shouldn't of watched haha